# React native custom view, no propType for native prop

Tags: android, react-native

I'm trying to implement a native view in react-native, but having some problems with the props.

I have a class `CustomView` extending the `android.view.View` and its `ViewManager` extending `com.facebook.react.uimanager.SimpleViewManager`.

The binding with React is done in this way:

```
'use strict';

var { requireNativeComponent, PropTypes } = require('react-native');

var iface = {
    name: 'CustomView',
    propTypes: {
        myProp: PropTypes.string
    },
};
module.exports = requireNativeComponent('CustomView', iface);
```

When I use it in my React app, it throws an error:

```
`CustomView` has no propType for native prop `CustomView.renderToHardwareTextureAndroid` of native type `boolean`
```

This is because `SimpleViewManager` has defined some standard property like:

```
@ReactProp(name = PROP_BACKGROUND_COLOR, defaultInt = Color.TRANSPARENT, customType = "Color")
public void setBackgroundColor(T view, int backgroundColor) {
    view.setBackgroundColor(backgroundColor);
}
```

I can fix it just declaring each property in my iface object.

I don't want to list manually all the props, is there a way to put all that props in my iface without have to know them?
Something like:

```
var {standardViewProps} = require('react-native');

var iface = {
    name: 'CustomView',
    propTypes: {
        ...standardViewProps,
        myProp: PropTypes.string
    }
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

EDIT 2017/06/02:

React Native 0.44 has deprecated the use of `View.propTypes`. Instead, do the following:

```
import { ViewPropTypes } from "react-native";

/* later... */
propTypes: {
    ...ViewPropTypes,
    myProp: PropTypes.string
}
```

---

PREVIOUS ANSWER:

Absolutely:

```
var View = React.View;

/* later... */
propTypes: {
    ...View.propTypes,
    myProp: PropTypes.string
}
```